# Keras implementation worse than tensorflow, is my implementation wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, keras

**Long Version (you may skip this)**

I'm rather new to both Tensorflow and Keras, I'm trying to use NLP for sentiment analysis (positive/negative sentences) I found the very famous [denny britz implementation](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/train.py) of the "Convolutional Neural Networks for Sentence Classification" paper and tried it out. The only difference between my implementation and the one I just linked is that I use pretrained vectors rather than training them on the spot.

It worked very well, using pretrained vectors I had an accuracy of 81% on my validation set after training on a small sample of my whole data.
However I then tried to move on my whole data and quickly ran out of both ram when training and disk space when saving the checkpoints.

The problem comes, among other things, from the way the implementation handles the sentences, for each sentence it stores the whole embedding of each word in that sentence rather than the indexes where those embeddings can be found in the pretrained embeddings file. So you can imagine how one would run out of memory with embeddings of dimension 300.

While looking for a way to make this more efficient by using indexes, I found out that Keras apparently had built-in support for that feature.

Thankfully, I found this [repository](https://github.com/alexander-rakhlin/CNN-for-Sentence-Classification-in-Keras/blob/master/sentiment_cnn.py) which apparently implements the denny britz implementation in Keras (with a few differences in the parameters which, according to the owner of the repository, shouldn't influence accuracy)

I had to somewhat modify the code for it to work with indexes rather than full embeddings and think that that part of my modifications was correct, you can find my code below. It's also worth nothing that the repository owner said his Keras was built on top of Theano and not Tensorflow, unlike mine. But after having read the differences I don't think this should be the cause of my problem.

**Short version**

I tried to modify the code found on the second link to make it as similar to the first link as possible, the resulting code (found below) runs but the result is not comparable. With the code in the first link I get an accuracy of 87% on the training set and 81% on the validation set after one epoch. With the code below those accuracies are of respectively 72% and 62%, which is way worse.

```
filter_sizes = [3, 4, 5]
num_filters = 128
hidden_dims = 50
dropout_prob = 0.5
max_sentence_len = 64
#(word embedding dimension = 300)


model_input = Input(shape=(max_sentence_len,), dtype='int32')

z =Embedding(word_embeddings.shape[0],
            word_embeddings.shape[1],
            input_length=max_sentence_len,
            weights=[word_embeddings],
            trainable=False)(model_input)

z = Dropout(dropout_prob)(z)

# Convolutional block
conv_blocks = []
for sz in filter_sizes:
    conv = Convolution1D(filters=num_filters,
                         kernel_size=sz,
                         padding="valid",
                         activation="relu",
                         strides=1)(z)
    conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv)
    conv = Flatten()(conv)
    conv_blocks.append(conv)
z = Concatenate()(conv_blocks) if len(conv_blocks) > 1 else conv_blocks[0]

z = Dropout(dropout_prob)(z)
z = Dense(hidden_dims, activation="relu")(z)
model_output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(z)

model = Model(model_input, model_output)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2,
          validation_split=0.05, verbose=1)
```

I've been trying to tweak some parameters/layers for the last few hours but I'm still not getting anywhere near the performance of the tensorflow implementation. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you controlling the random factor? In other words, did you reset the seeds `np.random.seed(seed)` and `tf.set_random_seed(seed)`?

Comment: The only seed used is in the TF implementation (to separate training and validation data), everything else is purely random in both TF and Keras. So in expectation if both implementations were equal I would get the same range of results, but the TF implementation is constantly more than 10% better than the Keras one.